# Unknown authentication strategy "local" (Error Passport)

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

Keep getting this error popping up. Checked and rechecked the code I have.

here is my passport.ts

```
 import * as express from 'express';
 import * as passport from 'passport';
 import * as session from 'express-session';
 let MySQLStore = require('express-mysql-session')(session);
 import { Strategy as LocalStrategy } from 'passport-local';
 import * as userProc from '../procedures/users.proc';
 import { pool } from './db';

 export default function configurePassport(app: express.Express) {
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email',
    passwordField: 'password',
}, (email, password, done) => {
    userProc.readByEmail(email)
        .then((user) => {
            if (!user) {
                return done(null, false, { message: 'Invalid login' });
            }
            if (user.password !== password) {
                return done(null, false, { message: 'Invalid login' });
            }
            return done(null, user);
        }, (err) => {
            return done(err);
        });
}));
```

I am importing Strategy only, from passport-local as LocalStrategy, in the controller I am importing passport but for some reason it throws this error. Here is the snippet from my controller code where I am trying to authenticate the local strategy.

```
    router.post('/login', (req, res, next) => {
    passport.authenticate('local', (err: any, user: models.IUser, info: any) 
=> {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return res.sendStatus(500);
        }
        if (!user) {
            return res.sendStatus(401);
        }
        req.logIn(user, (err) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return res.sendStatus(500);
            } else {
                delete user.password;
                return res.send(user);
            }
        });
    })(req, res, next);
});
```

Comment: Could you post the code you use to call `configurePassport`? I suggest adding some console logging to that function to confirm it is being called before you try to use the `local` strategy.

Comment: well...thanks that was it